# python array indexing list in list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I want to do array indexing. I would have expected the result to be [0,1,1,0], however I just get an error. How can I do this type of indexing?

```
a_np_array=np.array(['a','b','c','d'])
print a_np_array in ['b', 'c']

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "dfutmgmt_alpha_osis.py", line 130, in <module>
print a_np_array in ['b', 'c']
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Up top, i actually meant to say [False,True,True,False] not [0,1,1,0] as I want the bools so i can do indexing

Comment: OK. I checked the documentation and this seems to be what I am looking for. Can you explain why my method does not work? I am surprised that there is no kind of array index like method to do this.

Comment: I have moved my comment to answer with some more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you cannot use `[0,1,1,0]` for indexing here, so you're using the wrong term.

```
>>> a_np_array[[0,1,1,0]]  # Not useful at all
array(['a', 'b', 'b', 'a'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

If I understood this correctly you're simply trying to check whether items of `a_np_array` exist in `['b', 'c']`,  for that use `numpy.in1d`, but as it returns boolean array we just need to convert it integer array.

```
>>> np.in1d(a_np_array, ['b','c'])
array([False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> np.in1d(a_np_array, ['b','c']).astype(int)
array([0, 1, 1, 0])
```

**Coming to why `a_np_array in ['b', 'c']` didn't work?**

Here the `in` operator will call the [`__contains__`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b22755f8ab5f/Objects/listobject.c#l403) method of the list object(`['b', 'c']`) and then for each object in list Python will use the method [`PyObject_RichCompareBool`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_RichCompareBool) to compare each item to `a_np_array`. `PyObject_RichCompareBool` first of all simply checks if the items to be compared are the **same object**, i.e same `id()`, if yes return 1 right away otherwise call [`PyObject_RichCompare`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_RichCompare) on them. Hence this will work:

```
>>> a_np_array in [a_np_array, 'c', 'a']
True
```

But this won't:

```
>>> a_np_array in [a_np_array.copy(), 'c', 'a']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-405-dfe2729bd10b>", line 1, in <module>
    a_np_array in [a_np_array.copy(), 'c', 'a']
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Now Python will check whether the object returned by `PyObject_RichCompare` is already a boolean type, i.e `True` or `False`(This is done using [`PyBool_Check`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/bool.html#c.PyBool_Check) and [`Py_True`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/bool.html#c.Py_True)), if it is then return the result immediately otherwise call [`PyObject_IsTrue`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_IsTrue) to check whether the object can be considered a truthy object, this is done by calling `__nonzero__` method of the object. For a NumPy array this will end up calling `bool()` on the returned object which is going to raise an error you're getting. Here NumPy expects you to call either `all()` or `any()` to check whether all items are `True` or at least one.

```
>>> bool(a_np_array == 'a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-403-b7ced85c4f02>", line 1, in <module>
    bool(a_np_array == 'a')
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

---

Links to source code:

- [`list_contains`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b22755f8ab5f/Objects/listobject.c#l403)
- [`PyObject_RichCompareBool`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b22755f8ab5f/Objects/object.c#l725)
- [`PyObject_IsTrue`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b22755f8ab5f/Objects/object.c#l1235)

Answer (score 2):

Try this [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> print [int(x in ['b', 'c']) for x in a_np_array]
[0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Utilizing the fact that `int(True) == 1` and `int(False) == 0`